# Quantify shift between different categories

Tags: categorical-data, ordinal-data

Let us consider a ordinal variable with four values say A,B,C,D (A greater than B greater than C greater than D) and a person can have any of these values at a given point in time. I have data which has a timestamp and the state in which the person was present. I would like to quantify the shift between these categories in order to come up with a valid estimate.

1) For example if a person shifts from A -> D the numbers should be high and if he shifts from A-> B the overall number should be low.

2) How frequently does they change?

Lets consider the following two examples

Case A:
1:00:10 A

1:10:15 B

1:12:15 A

1:15:15 A

1:18:15 A

1:20:15 B

Case B:

1:00:10 A

1:10:15 A

1:12:15 D

1:15:15 D

1:18:15 A

1:20:15 A

The overall number for case A should be lower than Case B.

Thanks

Comment: `A greater than B greater than C greater than D` So, the categories are ordinal, not nominal, aren't they?

Comment: Oops.You are Right. I have changed the question

Comment: Is the distance between each adjacent pair equal? i.e. the jump from A to B is the same size as the jump from B to C? If so, you could just assign a numerical scale, so A=1, B=2, C=3, D=4 and then calculate the difference at each time stamp jump.

Comment: thanks @rocinante.In addition, I would like to take into account how often do they jump as well?

Comment: You need to be more concrete. What does your categories represent?  What is the time scale? about how many changes do you have per person? Do they always change in the same direction (in your example they do so)?  To what use will be put your model?  Modelling cannot be done in the absdtract, we need these details!